Synapse Workspace Trigger deployed via CI/CD in Azure DevOps always shows in a "Stopped" status
I am in the process of configuring an Azure Synapse Test and Production environment, and as part of this, have set up CI/CD based releases to both environments within Azure DevOps through the Synapse workspace validate and deploy tasks.
The only issue is that when trying to deploy a trigger in a started state, it always shows as "Stopped" when it is inevitably added/ updated in the target environment, even though the Trigger.json file it is referencing for the deployment shows the trigger as being in a "Started" state.
Is there any way of fixing this easily without having to set up an extra step in our release pipelines to enable them?

In the deployment, triggers will default to a "Stopped" state regardless of the "Started" status set in the Trigger.json file. This occurs because triggers cannot be updated while active; they need to be stopped prior to deployment and can only be restarted once the deployment is complete.
You can install the Synapse workspace deployment extension to use the Azure Synapse Toggle Triggers Dev task to start the trigger. You can refer the step 7 in this document:

To manage triggers, you can use trigger toggle to stop the triggers before deployment. And you can also add a task to restart the triggers after the deployment task.

